# How to use zufolge?

Tags: preposition

Working with some native German speakers, I presented the following sentence:

> Patienten sind auch körperlichen Aktivitäten mit geringer Intensität ***zufolge*** kurzatmig, beispielsweise ein kurzer Spaziergang.

They corrected me to the following sentence:

> Patienten sind auch ***nach*** körperlichen Aktivitäten mit geringer Intensität kurzatmig, beispielsweise ein kurzer Spaziergang.

I would appreciate an explanation regarding why my use of **zufolge** was incorrect.

Comment: Both [infolge](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/infolge) and [demzufolge](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/demzufolge) also exist.

Comment: Nach wem oder was? Beispielsweise einem kurzen Spaziergang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Zufolge* means *according to*. It is used to refer to a source.

*After* can be translated as *zufolge* only if it is used in this way, but not if it is used with a temporal or causal meaning, as in your example.

An example for the usage of *zufolge*:

> Gerüchten zufolge wird der Premierminister heute zurücktreten.
> According to rumours, the prime minister will resign today.

But *als Folge* can be used instead of *zufolge* in your example:

> Patienten sind auch als Folge körperlicher Aktivitäten mit geringer Intensität kurzatmig, beispielsweise nach einem kurzen Spaziergang [or: als Folge eines kurzen Spaziergangs].

However, using *können* would sound better here: *Patienten können auch als Folge körperlicher Aktivitäten kurzatmig sein, ...*